# How to check whether a user has write access to jfrog repository using jfrog CLI?

Tags: jfrog-cli

Is there any way to check whether a user has write access to a particular jfrog repository using jfrog CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Basically no. JFrog CLI has no command that checks permissions.

However, You can get it by negativity:
You can run the following command to dry-run an upload to the repository:

```
jf rt u <test-file> <repository> --dry-run --url <Artifactory Instance> --user <the user> --password <password>
```

It should be successful in dry-run.

Then you can run the same command without dry-run flag:

```
jf rt u <test-file> <repository> --url <Artifactory Instance> --user <the user> --password <password>
```

If it fails then the user doesn't have write permissions to that repository.

The side affect is that if he does have a write permission the test file will be uploaded to Artifactory and you can use jf rt dl to delete it after.

Comment: Thanks for replying, this wont wont. dry run will be successful, but actual upload will fail

Answer (score 0):

You can get permissions by name with REST API, If you want use CLI, just write a script for this options with `requests` library. This API you can see below:

```
$ curl -X GET -u user:password "http://ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_HOSTNAME:8082/distribution/api/v1/security/permissions/:name"
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "distribution_destinations": [
    {
      "site_name": "*",
      "city_name": "*",
      "country_codes": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "permission-name",
  "resource_type": "destination",
  "principals": {
    "users": {
      "anonymous": [
        "x"
      ]
    },
    "groups": {
      "readers": [
        "x"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Just get this permissions list with Admin.